# How to change DOM element and revoke it?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have SVG elements on the page. I try to change one then revoke changes:

```js
const button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
const button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
var elements = new Map();
var copy;

button1.addEventListener('click', event => {
   var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
      container = document.getElementById( 'cont' );
   for (var x = 0; x < 500; x += 50) {
      var circle = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'circle');
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', x);
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', x);
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', 50);
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', 'fill: none; stroke: blue; stroke-width: 1px;' );
      elements.set(x, circle);
      container.appendChild(circle);   
   }
});

button2.addEventListener('click', event => {
   let element = elements.get(50);
   copy = element.cloneNode(true);
   element.style.fill = "red";
});

button3.addEventListener('click', event => {
   let element = elements.get(50);
   element = copy;
   //console.log(element);
});
```

```html
<button id="button1">Build</button>
<button id="button2">Change</button>
<button id="button3">Revert</button>

<svg id="cont" height="1000" width="1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
</svg>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "revoke"? Do you mean to remove the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element = copy` is only going to change a *reference* to the DOM element, but not the DOM itself. For that you need to use the DOM API.

So replace that assignment with:

```
element.replaceWith(copy);
```

```js
const button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
const button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
var elements = new Map();
var copy;

button1.addEventListener('click', event => {
   var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
      container = document.getElementById( 'cont' );
   for (var x = 0; x < 500; x += 50) {
      var circle = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'circle');
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', x);
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', x);
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', 50);
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', 'fill: none; stroke: blue; stroke-width: 1px;' );
      elements.set(x, circle);
      container.appendChild(circle);   
   }
});

button2.addEventListener('click', event => {
   let element = elements.get(50);
   copy = element.cloneNode(true);
   element.style.fill = "red";
});

button3.addEventListener('click', event => {
   let element = elements.get(50);
   element.replaceWith(copy);
});
```

```html
<button id="button1">Build</button>
<button id="button2">Change</button>
<button id="button3">Revert</button>

<svg id="cont" height="1000" width="1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
</svg>
```